# Accessing resources (images and so) in html

Tags: javascript, html

From what i see in my web project, if i use some image twice (in my case svg file) it is being downloaded twice. 
Is there a way to access images/other resources in html through some id or something like that? maybe even by using javascript. What I want to achieve is a single download of every resource and multiple use of it.

Thanks.

Comment: In case you are actually using the same URI for the source file it should only be downloaded once. What makes you think otherwise?

Comment: I agree with @m90. It would only download once if it is the same url

Answer (score 2):

If the image is being downloaded twice then you need to look at the [cache control headers](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/) sent by the server. Browsers should download it once and then reuse the version in their cache for subsequent requests.